# How to Auto delete a image file that does not detect the face while running in the cmd - FER (python)

Tags: opencv, deep-learning, command-prompt

I was test running an deep learning algorithm (FER) and running 4,000 images and the speed is very slow and when it cant recognise an image in the command prompt it will stop running and I have to delete the image re-run the command prompt again. Is there a solution to auto delete a image in the command prompt if it cant recognise the facial expression image?

Comment: the file is in python.

Comment: when you say **re-run the command prompt again** do you mean run the program? If so can you include the code in your post?

Comment: I figured it out in the end but thanks for commenting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  results = k.detect_(image)
        stop = timeit.default_timer()
        if results == []:
            os.remove(content_image_path)
            print("This file is deleted:",content_image_path)
        else:
```

//use the if statement and below